# Is it possible to install eclipse without jdk in linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, java

I want to install eclipse in linux, Is it possible to install eclipse without jdk in linux. How to install eclipse in linux. Im using Federo 10. Please give the suggession.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Eclipse only need a JRE to run. It can compile classes using its own compiler, so it doesn't need an external JDK.

Though, a JDK is highly recommanded, and can be necessary for some plugins (M2Eclipse for Maven integration needs an external JDK, by example).

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse needs only the JRE to run, however, a JDK is recommended.
Install the rpm package for jdk, for example: jdk-6u10-linux-i586-rpm

Or use the nonRPM version.
You need to make the file executable:

chmod 755 jdk-6u10-linux-i586.bin

You should then be able to run that file. It will unpack the contents in the current directory, which you can then move to wherever you want. If you put the extracted directory (jdk1.6.0_10) in, say, /usr/local, then add /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_10/bin to your PATH:

export PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_10/bin:$PATH

You should then be able to run java, javac, etc.